# Table not responsive for mobile devices (using react-table)

Tags: tailwind-css, react-table, daisyui

As the title suggests, my table is not responsive for mobile devices. I applied overflow-x-auto but the scrollbar is not appearing. [This is how it looks on mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaDan.png)

This is my first time posting on stack overflow so if I did something wrong I apologize.

This is my current code. I have daisyui and tailwind installed.

```
<div className="overflow-x-auto">
                <table {...getTableProps()} className="table table-xs md:table-md lg:table-lg mt-10 border-collapse">
                  <thead>
                    {headerGroups.map((headerGroup, idx) => (
                      <tr key={idx} {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                        {headerGroup.headers.map((column, idx) => (
                          <th key={idx} {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                            {column.render("Header")}
                          </th>
                        ))}
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                  </thead>
                  <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                    {page.map((row, idx) => {
                      prepareRow(row);
                      return (
                        <tr key={idx} {...row.getRowProps()}>
                          {row.cells.map((cell, idx) => (
                            <td key={idx} {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                              {cell.render("Cell")}
                            </td>
                          ))}
                        </tr>
                      );
                    })}
                  </tbody>
                </table>

                <div className="mt-12 flex flex-col space-y-1 md:flex-row justify-between items-center">
                  <span>
                    Go to Page :{" "}
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      className="w-12 border"
                      defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        const pageNumber = e.target.value
                          ? Number(e.target.value) - 1
                          : 0;
                        gotoPage(pageNumber);
                      }}
                    />
                  </span>
                  <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1 md:flex-row justify-center items-center gap-6">
                    <button
                      className="btn bg-rose text-white"
                      onClick={() => previousPage()}
                      disabled={!canPreviousPage}
                    >
                      Previous
                    </button>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => gotoPage(0)}
                      disabled={!canPreviousPage}
                      className="text-rose font-bold"
                    >
                      {"<<"}
                    </button>
                    <span>
                      Page{" "}
                      <strong>
                        {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
                      </strong>{" "}
                    </span>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)}
                      disabled={!canNextPage}
                      className="text-rose font-bold"
                    >
                      {">>"}
                    </button>
                    <button
                      className="btn bg-rose text-white"
                      onClick={() => nextPage()}
                      disabled={!canNextPage}
                    >
                      Next
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row lg:gap-2">
                    <h1>Rows in page</h1>
                    <select
                      className="border"
                      value={pageSize}
                      onChange={(e) => setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))}
                    >
                      <option value="3">Show 3</option>
                      <option value="5">Show 5</option>
                      <option value="10">Show 10</option>
                      <option value="15">Show 15</option>
                      <option value="20">Show 20</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```